# Can't display map data

Tags: c++, dictionary, vector

```
// Map created
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> _map;

// Key/Data inserted
_map.insert(std::pair<int, std::vector<int> >(0, { i }));

// Display values [ERROR]
for (const auto &p : _map) 
{       
  std::cout << "m[" << p.first << "] = " << p.second << '\n';   
}
```

It is a very simple program of creating a map, inserting values and display both key/pair by iterating over the entire map. **I am able to display map key (p.first) but I am not able to display the value of data (p.second).**

> Error C2679: binary '<<' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::vector>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Comment: What do you think p.second returns? It returns a vector of ints so you need to write an inner for loop to go through the vector and print the ints there. A vector does not define the << operator. Also you are using the new standard so instead of making a temporary pair to the insert function you can use brace initialisation._map.insert({0, {i}})

Comment: I can't access the p.second value, then how would I be able to use it to create nested loop? can you please give a small example? thank you

Comment: You can access it. std::cout does not have operator << which could take a vector as parameter. Add some inner loop like that: `for(auto &pp : p.second) {std::cout<<pp; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`p.second` in the `std::vector<int>` and the Standard Library does not overload `operator<<` for `vector`s, as stated by the error message.  So you'll have to add an inner loop to go through the `vector` and print the values it contains.

Instead of...

```
std::cout << "m[" << p.first << "] = " << p.second << '\n';
```

...try...

```
std::cout << "m[" << p.first << "] = {";
for (int n : p.second)
     std::cout << ' ' << n;
std::cout << " }\n";
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can print the content of `p.second` using `std::copy`

```
std::copy(p.second.begin(), p.second.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
```

For a more general solution, I suggest using the great [C++ container pretty print library](http://louisdx.github.io/cxx-prettyprint/). That library makes your code work without further alterations:

```
std::cout << p.second << std::endl;
```

Comment: I like the fact that it is a one-line instruction. Let me remove the comment on the convenience of this approach so as to present it in a more neutral way.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to define the `operator >>` for `std::vector` yourself

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream & operator >>(std::ostream & out, const std::vector<T> & vec) {
    std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end(), std::ostream_iterator<T>(out, " "));
    return out;
}
```

Your code will work as is after you add this definition.

```
for (const auto & p : _map)  {       
    std::cout << "m[" << p.first << "] = " << p.second << '\n';   
}
```